# nginx basic auth don't work on windows

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

This is my a part of nginx conf （window2003 server）

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  xxx.example.com;
  access_log  logs/example.com.log;

  location / {
    auth_basic  "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  c:/xxx/password_file;
    proxy_set_header  Authorization "";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000/xx/;
  }
}
```

Visit  `xxx.exmaple.com` site tips my input username & password（correct）, repeat this tips again and again。

> 1. password_file is created by `htpassword` command on Mac OS.
> 2. http://127.0.0.1:3000/xx/ proxy for tomcat application .
> 3. nginx version is `1.7.12` for window.

May be HttpBasicAuthModule with nginx not support windows platform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its;

```
auth_basic  "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file  c:/xxx/password_file;
```

See http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254125,254187#msg-254187

Comment: Amended with answer and example.